# How to detect if vue-router is used in current Vue instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vue-sfc

I want to develop a library with vue.js component inside. This component will have navigation elements inside. I want it to work with and without vue router. In router mode it should use `<router-link>` and if no router is used it should return standard `<a>` tags.

```
<template>
       <div>
            <div v-if="vueRouterIsUsed">
                <router-link v-bind:to="url">Router link</router-link>
            </div>
            <div v-else>
                <a :href="url">No router</a>
            <div>
       </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default{
        props: {
            url: {
                type: String,
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

1. How to detect if vue-router is used in current Vue instance?
2. Is there a better way that if/else for doing `<router-link>` to `<a>` fallback if no router is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in the created (or mounted) lifecycle hook what is in `this.$router` you can access all the routes and the router object, which means you can check what you need. Set the isRouter variable based on that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Vue3, you can use [getCurrentInstance](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance) like this :

```js
const isVueRouterInstalled =
  !!getCurrentInstance().appContext.config.globalProperties.$router;
```

However, as the documentation says :

> getCurrentInstance is only exposed for advanced use cases, typically in libraries. Usage of getCurrentInstance is strongly discouraged in application code